# Cookies are not sent to client (static web app) - Azure Isolated Function

Tags: .net-core, cookies, azure-functions, cross-domain, azure-static-web-app

When sending cookies as a response to a request in an included functions API (as part of a static web app), the cookies are not sent. This only occurs in a deployed static web app - this issue is not present in local testing of the API functions.

**Notes:** I have allowed static web site url to Azure functions website (CORS)

my code to add cookie through function:

```
{
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("serialno", "121345678");                    
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(6);
cookie.SameSite = SameSite.Strict;
cookie.Path = "/";
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
HttpResponseData response = JsonResponseObject(req, loginResponse);
response.Cookies.Append(cookie);
return response;
}

internal static HttpResponseData JsonResponseObject(HttpRequestData req, object data)
        {
            var response = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            response.Body = ObjectToStream(data);
            return response;

        }
```

The cookie should be set, just like how it works when testing API functions locally.

Comment: did you manage to find the solution finally? We are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The response object shouldn't be created as a part of your code, it is one of the function's arguments:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
...
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: ...
    };
}
```